# keytool error command

Tags: java, import, keytool

Hi I want to ask about my error when I import Certificate using keytool
this the error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\imig.cer -keystore C:\Program File
s (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, Files is not a legal command`

please help my error code in keytool..
Thanks before

Answer (score 7):

The error says that it's trying to interpret `Files` as a command.

That's because `-keystore` argument is truncated after space - to just `C:\Program`

To avoid truncation please surround the full path with double quotes:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\imig.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit`

If it results in another error - post a separate question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to quote the path because of the spaces.