# SSL Keystore path error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, keytool

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\Program Files\etc\etc
```

keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage Error, C:\Program Files is not a legal command

I've followed the advice given here [keytool error command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276102/keytool-error-command) but the error persists. What could be wrong?

I also tried

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\
```

In this case I fill up all the details (Password/First and Last Name/City etc) and finally I get

keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\

Comment: when there is any space in path you need to cover it in inverted commas like this "C:\Program Files\etc\etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore "C:\Program Files\etc\etc"
```

When there is any space in path you need to cover it in inverted commas.

Also note that path provided in the -keystore argument should be a path to file which will be generated as the keystore.

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\
```

The above command is not working because `C:\` is a directory path not file path.

Comment: Now I get this error - keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Program Files" <The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect>